# How to trigger click of a radio button inside a collapsible in jquery?

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have this collapsible

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" id="d27" name="d27" class="ui-block-a">
    <h4></h4>
    <div class="ui-block-a">
    <legend>D27: Yes or no?</legend>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <input type="radio" name="radioName" id="si27" value="1" />
        <label for="si27">Sì</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radioName" id="no27" value="0" checked="checked" />
        <label for="no27">No</label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to set programmatically, under certain circumstances, the value checked to No. If i put the radio outside the collapsible this works perfectly:

```
  $('#no27').trigger("click");
```

Inside it's not working. What am i missing?

I guess i haven't understood the way jquery find elements in a html page. If you can, also, point out some illuminating article it would be great ^^

Comment: Please post the code that runs on click of `#no27`

Comment: no code is run on click of #no27. Simple i need to set the value of the radio to No as the collapsible (initially collapsed) is been expanded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is because you have to `refresh` the elements you update when using jQuery Mobile or jQuery UI.

This will work:

```
$("#no27").prop("checked", true);
$("#d27").find("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Using `.prop()` the checked value of `#no27` is set to `true`. The second line then refreshes the radio buttons inside `#d27` using `.checkboxradio("refresh")`.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/ssKaV/, here's an interactive toggling example: http://jsfiddle.net/XxRvs/

Comment: Perfect! I was struggling with this since yesterday. The problem was exactly the lack of the Refresh. Now works like a charm. Thank you!